# How to use Wordpress Conditional Tags in get_posts foreach loop

Tags: get-posts, conditional-tags, php

I have a page which has a [jquery tab function](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to output the list of pages that are the children of this page (Bio, Archives, Contact).

However I am trying to make a conditional in the foreach loop to no avail.

```
<?php // get_posts function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Examples
$args = array( 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => array( 3, 4, 5, 6 ), /* Bio, Client, Archives, Contact */
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args ); ?>

    <ul class="tablinks"> 
        <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li id="page-<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>">
                <a href="#<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li> 
        <?php endforeach;  ?>
    </ul>

    <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <div class="tabcontents" id="<?php global $post; echo $post_slug=$post->post_name; ?>">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <!-- If this query is the Archives query, I would like to show thumbnails from this page's custom fields -->
            <?php edit_post_link("Edit"); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Basically, I would like to output the featured image of the children pages under Archives for when user views the Archives tab. I tried using this inside the foreach loop but it didn't work:

```
<?php if ( is_page( 5 ) || is_page('Archives') ) {
    echo 'Show me!';
} ?>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I wonder if you mean:

```
if( 5 == $post->ID 
    || 'archive' === mb_strtolower( $post->post_title ) 
    || 'archive' === $post->post_name )
{
    echo 'Show me';
}
```

when you generate the HTML for the tabs.

ps: If you check the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L472) of `is_page()` you will see that it returns `$wp_query->is_page( $page )`, where it uses the global `$wp_query` object. So it's mainly used for *main queries* but not *sub queries*.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php // get_posts function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Examples
$args = array( 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => array( 3, 4, 5, 6 ), /* Bio, Client, Archives, Contact */
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args ); ?>

    <ul class="tablinks"> 
        <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li id="page-<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>">
                <a href="#<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li> 
        <?php endforeach;  ?>
    </ul>

    <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <div class="tabcontents" id="<?php global $post; echo $post_slug=$post->post_name; ?>">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php if($post->ID=='5'){ //output featured image } ?>
            <!-- If this query is the Archives query, I would like to show thumbnails from this page's custom fields -->
            <?php edit_post_link("Edit"); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```